# What determines if a material tends to undergo transgranular or intergranular fracure?

Tags: crystallography, physical-properties-of-materials

As an example, why does glass tend to break by means of intergranular fracture?

My analysis so far led me to believe that the tendency can be related to the intermolecular bond strength in a given crystal grain and the intergranular bond strength. A stronger bond means better load bearing. If the intermolecular bond is stronger than the intergranular bond, then a material is more likely to experience intergranular fracture. But is this correct?

Comment: You can wait to see if you get an answer here, but this question may get a better response at [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have yet to find a satisfactory answer. Nevertheless, I am still open for answers. Not that I am in dire need, since I asked out of curiosity.

Comment: I think this question might have had a better chance of getting answered at Engineering.SE or elsewhere because it's more about properties than about modeling. Since you're not in dire need, let's remove it from the unanswered queue, because our priority is to help matter modeling researchers who are in dire need. People will still be able to answer via comments and even posting a full fledged answer if they simply request for us to re-open the question.